# Issue plotting a particular vector field

Tags: plotting

I am attempting to recreate a vector field plot for $\frac{dy}{dx}=3y^\frac{2}{3}$.  The graph should look like this figure below.
[image]

I tried

```
VectorPlot[{1, 3*y^(2/3)}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

to no avail.  However, if replace {y, -1, 1} with {y, 0, 1} I do successfully get the upper half of the plot. Is this because of the non-unique solutions on the line $y=0$?

Regardless, I would still like to recreate the plot above as it is correct and whats shown in my textbook.  Any ideas?

Comment: `VectorPlot[{1, 3*Surd[y^2, 3]}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, -1, 1}]` or `VectorPlot[{1, 3*y^(2/3) // Re}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, -1, 1}]`

Comment: Ahh!!! Got it!  Thank you.